# Firebase Function how to call a region real time database

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am struggling with one issue:

I have a cloud function that trigger on the realtime database

```
  .ref("/games/...")
  .onWrite(async (change) => {
```

It's working pretty well on the default realtime database (asia) but not on the europe-west1

So I tried functions.regions('europe-west1').database but no success, I couldn't find any help online.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`.region()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#modify-region) specifies where the Cloud function will run and has nothing to with database. You are probably looking for [`instance()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_database#instance):

> `instance()` registers a function that triggers on events from a specific Firebase Realtime Database instance.

By default `functions.database.ref` used without `instance` watches the *default* instance for events and that's why the trigger works for your default DB in Asia.

```
firebase.database.instance('my-app-db-2').ref('/foo/bar').onWrite(async (change) => {})
```

Checkout ['specify the instance and path'](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#specify_the_instance_and_path) section in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you, I already tried to use instance('europe-west1'), instance('url of my database') and many variation but I am not allowed to deploy my functions.

Comment: @Ocelyn can you share a screenshot of what have you tried? You just need to pass instance name not URL or region. `https://<INSTANCE_NAME>.firebaseio.com/` -> `.instance('INSTANCE_NAME')`

Comment: Thank you for your help

functions.database.instance("project-xxx").ref("/games...").onWrite(async (change) => {

with my instance URL like this: https://project-xxx.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/

Comment: Ok I created a new database instance still in Europe and this time it worked. Very weird.

Comment: @Ocelyn unsure, that worked for me first time itself.